# Docker run and sqlcmd together errors

Tags: powershell, docker, sqlcmd, sql-server-linux

Putting together a script to quickly add a SQL Server Linux instance inside a docker container, then immediately connecting to it to test. Seems like the run command and sqlcmd can't be run in the same script.

Say you run this in a .ps1 file:

```
  #create the container with sql server
  docker run `
  -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Awesome1!" `
     -p 11433:1433 `
     --name shuriken --hostname shuriken --restart=always `
     -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest;

  #try to connect to it
  $ConnectionString = "Server=localhost,11433;Database=master;User Id=sa; Password=Awesome1!";
  $sql = 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName;';
  Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionString -Query $sql;
```

You get an error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A connection was successfully established with the
>   server, but then an error occurred during the  pre-login handshake.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote  host.)

But if after that you immediately comment out the `docker run` command, it works. Connects to the same SQL Server just fine:

> shuriken

I've tried `Invoke-SqlCmd`, `SqlCmd`, cmdlets from the SqlServer module and placing them in another file I call here; they all give the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `Start-Sleep -s 4;` between `docker run` and `Invoke-SqlCmd` works.
Looks like it just needed some breathing room.
4 seconds was the lowest I could go before querying.